# How to traverse an n-ary tree as an iterator or stream

Tags: scala

I would like to create a function in my Tree class to traverse an n-ary Tree[T] to get back a tuple with (level, T) so that users of that Tree can do things like

```
tree.traverse.foreach{ case(l, t) => printf("%-30s %s", "  "*l + t.id, info(t))
```

to get a report like this

```
rootnode                       
  n1.0                         
    n1.0.1                     >> n1.0.1
    n1.0.2                     >> n1.0.2
    n1.0.3                     >> n1.0.3
  n3.0                         
    n3.0.1                     >> n1.0.1
      n3.0.1.1                 >> n1.0.1
```

The tree node is

```
class TreeNode[T](val id: String, 
          private var _data: Option[T],
          private var _parent: String, 
          private var _treeNodeType: TreeNodeType) {
  private var _children: Set[String] = Set()
  ...
}
```

I can traverse the tree recursively using the traverse or traversef

```
class Tree[T] {
  private val ROOT = "rootnode"
  val rootNode = new TreeNode(ROOT, None.asInstanceOf[Option[T]], "", ROOTNODETYPE)
  var hmTree: HashMap[String, TreeNode[T]] = HashMap(ROOT -> rootNode)

def traverse: Unit = {
  def iter(s: String, l: Int): Unit = {
    val n = hmTree(s)
    printf("%-30s\n", "  "*l + n.id)
    n.children.foreach(c => iter(c, l+1))
  }
  iter(ROOT, 0)
}

def traversef(f: Option[T] => String): Unit = {
  def iter(s: String, l: Int): Unit = {
    val n = hmTree(s)
    printf("%-30s %s\n", "  "*l + n.id, f(n.data))
    n.children.foreach(c => iter(c, l+1))
  }
  iter(ROOT, 0)
}

...
```

I looked at http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/11275.html (Question: How to implement lazy traversal of n-ary tree using Streams?) but couldn't get the code to work. The thing that tripped me was how to Stream.cons the children.

I am ok with either a stream or an iterator. Key is to define the traverse method in the Tree class and use it outside.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Many thanks to @Archeg -- here is the working traverse

```
def traverse(t: TreeNode[T], depth: Int = 0): Stream[(TreeNode[T], Int)] = {  
  (t, depth) #:: t.children.foldLeft(Stream.empty[(TreeNode[T], Int)]) { 
          case (aggr, el) => aggr #::: traverse(hmTree(el), depth+ 1)   
  }
}

tree.traverse(tree.rootNode).
  foreach{ case(t, l) => printf("%-30s %s\n", "  "*l + t.id, t.id) }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made it simple so it would be easy to figure it out:

```
 case class Tree[T](data: T, children: List[Tree[T]])

 def traverse[T](t: Tree[T]): Stream[T] =
    t.data #:: t.children.foldLeft(Stream.empty[T])((aggr, el) => aggr #::: traverse(el))
```

**Upd**

A slightly modified version which provides you with indentation:

```
def traverseInd[T](t: Tree[T], depth: Int = 0): Stream[(T, Int)] =
    (t.data, depth) #:: t.children.foldLeft(Stream.empty[(T, Int)]) { 
            case (aggr, el) => aggr #::: traverseInd(el, depth+ 1)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - let me try that.

Comment: @Bernie Please see my update for the traversal with indentation - I've missed that first time I was writing the code

Comment: THANKS!!! Your suggestion worked. I updated my question with the final traverse (only because comments don't support multi-line code formatting). Thanks again!!

Comment: @Bernie If you think my answer is fit, please accept it. I appreciate it, but no need to say thanks - this usually is implicitly meant by accepting an answer and it is considered an offtopic on SO